# How to find reason for unexpected shutdown of tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat7

We are running a java application on Apache tomcat 7. But it suddenly went shutdown. I searched in `catalina.out` logs. Normally our server will restart automatically at 2 am as per script. But when I checked in `apport.log` it says :

```
ERROR: apport (pid 18768) Wed Nov 13 09:18:54 2019: called for pid 17915, signal 6
ERROR: apport (pid 18768) Wed Nov 13 09:18:54 2019: executable: executable: /opt/biller-java/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/java (command line "/opt/myapplication-java/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/tomcats/apache-tomcat-7.0.64-myapplication/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Xms512m -Xmx4000m -XX:PermSize=128m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/tomcats/apache-tomcat-7.0.64-myapplication/endorsed -classpath /tomcats/apache-tomcat-7.0.64-myapplication/bin/bootstrap.jar:/tomcats/apache-tomcat-7.0.64-biller/bin/tomcat-juli.jar -Dcatalina.base=/tomcats/apache-tomcat-7.0.64-biller -Dcatalina.home=/tomcats/apache-tomcat-7.0.64-myapplication -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tomcats/apache-tomcat-7.0.64-myapplication/temp org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start")
ERROR: apport (pid 18768) Wed Nov 13 09:18:54 2019: executable does not belong to a package, ignoring
```

Currently our server shutdown around this time. How can I find the actual reason for this issue eventhough it worked after tomcat restart. But I want to know the actual reason?

Comment: How about starting with the tips shown here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003738/tomcat-shuts-down-automatically ?

Comment: Thank you for the link.But it didnt mention anything about the apport.log.This application was working perfectly for about 1 year.It is the first time it got crashed.No information in catalina.out ,debug.log etc.